# What is the technology used in the phones which reduces blur in the photos even if they are zoomed?

Tags: camera, photos

What is the technology used in the phones which reduces blur in the photos even if they are zoomed?

In our old mobile phones, our phone camera pictures used to look blurred when the are zoomed. But now, it is not the case. Which technology is responsible for the reduced blur?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [autofocus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofocus)?

> An autofocus (or AF) optical system uses a sensor, a control system
>   and a motor to focus fully automatic or on a manually selected point
>   or area.

Comment: I believe he is talking about the reduction in pixelation due to the increase in megapixels of photograps. From earlier VGA to mega pixels for images. 

Your answer also seems right, considering the older mobile cameras had fixed focus.

Comment: The focus has nothing to do with "zooming into pictures" (which are already taken). I'd say it's rather Interpolation or Upscaling. Devices of today have much more processing power, and thus can provide/use much better/efficient algorithms for this.